# Resizing my page make items disappear

Tags: html, css

When the webpage become too small some part of it disappear but I would like to make it stay the way it's positioned but resize with the page no matter how small it becomes.

[Here's the problem](https://puu.sh/oUUA1/caa15ba38e.webm)

Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body{
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
}
#picture {
    text-align: center;
    position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
    <title>lllllllllll</title>
<body>
    <div id="picture">
        <a href="c.html"><img src="c.png" alt="llllll" width="33%" height="100%" /></a>
        <a href="n.html"><img src="n.png" alt="llllll" width="33%" height="100%" /></a>
        <a href="m.html"><img src="m.png" alt="llllll" width="33%" height="100%" /></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: paste your html code please

Comment: Please post your code it will be useful to recognize your question

Comment: @willie Not only useful but necessary. There is so many possibilities why that could be happening that we can have thousands of attempts an never solve the problem.

Comment: @thepio Yeah ! Definitely you are right but for the new members ,maybe need to a little time to understand  , by the way please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful for you to lift your content quality up

Comment: @willie Yep, of course it will take some time for new members :) Good that people are helping by commenting!

Comment: First issue I see is the lack of a <head> section in Your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

First and foremost, Your basic HTML structure should be as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- CONTENT -->
</body>

</html>
```

And about Your main problem, try and use CSS to style your layout instead of assigning inline properties like `width="33%"` and others alike. Right now, your images are stretching because of the inlined properties which are not the same as a style applied to them.

By using these properties on your images, you are telling them to be 33% of their container, but images are not **[block elments](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)** so therefore, they need to be in a container, for example a div.

e.g.

```
<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="img.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

I have made a **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juqeek04/)** for you to try it yourself.

> When someone here on StackOverflow says "here is a Fiddle" or something similar, what they mean is, they have created a small online coding environment that acts as a [**sandbox**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)) for your project. You have your HTMl, CSS, Javascript and Output, alongside options for adding external content as well. https://jsfiddle.net/

I have changed a few things here and there to show you an example of basic usage. Please feel free to ask what You dont understand.

Comment: A question I have is what does the "a div" stand for in "#picture a div {" and for some reason when I add it to my code it doesn't change anything yet I can clearly see it's effect on the JS Fiddle

Comment: Basic CSS selector. #picutre is your image container div, inside it there are anchor elements <a></a> and inside those elements I added a div just for demo purposes. Which basically means, I want to style the <div> element inside the <a> element that is inside #picture

Comment: Try and go trough a CSS basics tutorial first, like this one here:

http://www.csstutorial.net/css-intro/introductioncss-part1.php